# is it possible to get the duration of a streaming mp3 in Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, audio-streaming

I'm wondering if it is at all possible to get the total duration of an mp3 being streamed in flash?

At the moment I'm using the following code to estimate the lenght but it is always inaccurate

```
var loadTime:Number=_track.bytesLoaded / _track.bytesTotal;
var loadPercent:uint=Math.round(100 * loadTime);
estimatedLength=Math.ceil(_track.length / (loadTime));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The long and short of it is if you are playing a streaming mp3 in flash it is impossible to get the exact total playing time until the mp3 is completely downloaded

Answer (score 0):

I don't program in AS3, but can you not read the Length attribtue in the header of the file prior to streaming it?

Answer (score 0):

`Sound` class has a [`length` property](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/media/Sound.html#length). This property will be populated once the relevant `id3` data for the sound file is loaded. Check out [flash.events.Event.ID3](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/media/Sound.html#event:id3) for more info on `id3` data.

Comment: Yeah but you only get this once the mp3 has download fully.... or as far as I can see anyway. It constantly changes until the mp3 is fully downloaded

Comment: how about listening to `id3` event - did u try that?

Comment: yeah, unfortunately I don't have control over the encoding of the mp3's and often times the lenght property seems to be blank. It was the TLEN attribute of the id3 I've been trying to access anyway